# Reload a Web Page Using C#

Tags: c#

I have a web page that prompts for user input via DropDownLists in some table cells.  When a selection is made the selection replaces the DropDownList so that the action can only be performed once.  In the case that a change needs to be made I want to be able to click a button that reloads the page from scratch.  I have Googled and Googled but I have not managed to find a way to do this.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an OnClick for your button that resets each DropDownList's SelectedIndex to 0 instead of reloading the page from scratch. Alternatively, you can set a Response.Redirect([the page's url]) into the OnClick as is suggested [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t232190-how-to-clear-viewstate-in-aspx-or-ascx-page.html).

Answer (score 3):

Put a link on the page with the text "Reload" and the url the url of the page.  It's perfectly valid to have a page with a link to itself.

If you don't like the link idea, use a standard Button and in the click event, use Response.Redirect to redirect to the current page.